# GPIO state in code changes, but mechanical relay doesn't change

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

I have a Raspberry Pi 3 Model B hooked up to a SainSmart 16 channel mechanical relay. I have a python script to change the state of the relays, and while the state in the program changes for the different GPIO channels, the mechanical relay never changes state.

Does anyone have any ideas?

**My python script**

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
sleepTime = 0.5

pinList = [4, 17, 27, 22, 10, 9, 11, 5, 6, 13, 19, 26, 21, 20, 16, 12]

for i in pinList:
    GPIO.setup(i, GPIO.OUT)

for i in pinList:
    time.sleep(sleepTime);
    GPIO.output(i, GPIO.HIGH)
    print (str(i) + " high")
    print ("state: " + str(GPIO.input(i)))

for i in pinList:
    time.sleep(sleepTime);
    GPIO.output(i, GPIO.LOW)
    print(str(i) + " low")
    print ("state: " + str(GPIO.input(i)))

GPIO.cleanup()
```

**The output of the script**

```
4 high
state: 1
17 high
state: 1
27 high
state: 1
22 high
state: 1
10 high
state: 1
9 high
state: 1
11 high
state: 1
5 high
state: 1
6 high
state: 1
13 high
state: 1
19 high
state: 1
26 high
state: 1
21 high
state: 1
20 high
state: 1
16 high
state: 1
12 high
state: 1
4 low
state: 0
17 low
state: 0
27 low
state: 0
22 low
state: 0
10 low
state: 0
9 low
state: 0
11 low
state: 0
5 low
state: 0
6 low
state: 0
13 low
state: 0
19 low
state: 0
26 low
state: 0
21 low
state: 0
20 low
state: 0
16 low
state: 0
12 low
state: 0
```

Thanks for reading.

Comment: What are the electrical characteristics of your relay?

Comment: Uses a transistor to activate relay

Comment: This is the relay: http://www.sainsmart.com/16-channel-12v-relay-module-for-pic-arm-avr-dsp-arduino-msp430-ttl-logic.html

Comment: use my solution, change 12Vdc to 5Vdc(battery)

Answer (score 0):

[image: Raspberry Pi 3 GPIO diagram]

Using the above diagram I had originally connected both of the 5v pins (pin 2 and 4) to the corresponding pins on the relay module. I then started connected GPIO pins starting from GPIO4 (pin 7), moving down the left column of GPIO pins then up the right side. For the grounds I used pin 6 and pin 9. This is how I had things setup when I asked the question.

**But by moving the 5v cable from pin 2 to pin 1 (the 3.3v), that solved my problem.**

Note: I got the diagram from https://www.element14.com/community/docs/DOC-73950/l/raspberry-pi-3-model-b-gpio-40-pin-block-pinout